# Using ViewPager and PagerTabStrip - extending FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

First - sorry for the newbish question.

I've started building an app that has a single Activity and a navigation drawer. Each menu item loads a new fragment in the middle frame layout.

I want to create another fragment that:

1. has tabs
2. allows for swipe scrolling

It seems like the only way to do this is to create add a ViewPager and PagerTabStrip. All the tutorials I've read indicate the ViewPager requires extending out to FragmentActivity. I have a few questions:

1. Am I doing anything wrong by replacing the fragment content when navigating menu options?
2. If what I am doing is ok, is there anyway to incorporate swipe navigation without calling FragmentActivity?
3. If I need to use FragmentActivity for this one page, I'm assuming I'll call change pages via Intent. Doing so would result in losing the click actions in the navigation drawer. Do I have to call (or duplicate) my code from one activity to another?

*EDIT*

Sorry about the confusion. Here's what I'd like my application do:

1. Open app. MainActivity starts. Navigation drawer loads. Main content is loaded via a fragment.
2. User opens navigation drawer and selects this new menu item I'm creating. It is a new fragment that loads in the frame (like the other menu items). However, it has tabs and supports swiping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewPager` is just usual descendant of `View` so it can't require using of `FragmentActivity`.

1. It's absolutely ok.
2. You don't need to use `FragmentActivity`. I suppose you just read tutorial about "Implementation of drawer" where author of the tutorial used `FragmentActivity`.
3. Can't understand what do you mean. Pages of `ViewPager` is just views not activities. You don't need to use `Intent`.

`PS` Actually I can't understand your problem at all. It's absolutely  unclear why you don't want to use `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very clear. The PagerTabStrip will be calling other fragments within the ViewPager. The part I'm confused about is the examples (like this one: https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/) which requires using getSupportFragmentManager(). This is an extension of FragmentActivity.

Comment: So? `SupportFragmentManager` is just for old versions for android. What's the problem?

Comment: grrrr i'm a dummy. I posted the wrong link - but there is no problem. My issue was my pager adapter class was extending FragmentPagerAdapter. extending FragmentPagerAdapter requires a constructor with fragmentmanager being passed. When setting my ViewPager adapter I needed to pass the fragment manger, which my fragment did not have. I forgot getActivity().. that's all. =) Thanks for your patience and for answering my question on how I'm using fragments.

Comment: I also realize without posting code explaining my issue makes things difficult! I've noted this for future posts of mine.

Comment: There is `PagerAdapter` which does not require `FragmentManager`: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html :) Fragment related classes could as help you but also could be a problem.